# Starting out in film/tv post/scoring (bgm)

Tags: audio, music, post-production, film

So I've put together a film/tv post/scoring system, and was looking to expand my portfolio by donating my time to a worthy project. Are there any solutions better than the local craigslist? I'd prefer to skip the clowns and lunatics that entails, and my school is giving me some work but not a huge amount.

Many thanks in advance

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to probably look for production companies in the area and see if you can work with any of them.  Generally, a lot of the production guys in an area know each other from working on projects and it's typically a pretty informal network.  The best bet is to start out with an actual production company and get to know people from there.  They might also be able to point you towards other people with projects going on if they don't have anything at the moment.

Comment: To add, if you have trouble getting ins with any production companies, try checking out local film making classes and talks that are directed at other disciplines, like DPs and screen writers, and make friends there and tell them you'd love to get involved on the audio side. They can point you to some of their colleagues or even give you the gig if you have some decent samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try Kickstarter! Lots of talented people looking to get their films made. Get in touch with them, sell them on your skills, and get that portfolio growing.